# How is user input sanitized?

Tags: 8, webforms, security

I had to develop a Drupal 8 based website for a client. This client has a quite strict configuration for its firewall and filters the characters used in POST values. It happens to be a bit too restrictive on the contact form for the taste of the marketing department. The security team would consent to lift some character limitations if I could list them the measures used by Drupal and Webform to filter/sanitize user inputs.

I am pretty confident that Drupal does a good job in that regard. I expect a mixture of `htmlentities()`, `filter_var()`, custom functions calls and other related configurations but I couldn't find any details. All my searches on the subject spawns answers around the fact that Drupal *does* sanitize its input, but nothing concrete.

How does Drupal sanitize the user input?

Comment: The key thing to note, which Clive mentioned below, is that input is saved as-is, and is only filtered for output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal uses Twig's [autoescape](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/autoescape.html) feature, which in turn uses [`escape`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html), which itself uses `htmlspecialchars` to prepare markup safe for output.

[`SafeMarkup::checkPlain()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21SafeMarkup.php/function/SafeMarkup%3A%3AcheckPlain/8.2.x) preceded the autoescaping (deprecated now), so you may see that used, and [`HTML::escape`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3Aescape/8.2.x) can be used if you need to do it manually for whatever reason.

As with all versions of Drupal, [filtering is done on output only](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/security/why-does-drupal-filter-on-output), not input, so `filter_var` and friends aren't involved.